# this.initialize(arguments) vs this.initialize.apply(this, arguments): what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If you have a look at Backbone.js's source code, you'll see multiple uses of this pattern:

```
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

For example, here:

```
  var Router = Backbone.Router = function(options) {
    options || (options = {});
    if (options.routes) this.routes = options.routes;
    this._bindRoutes();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Why not just write `this.initialize(arguments)` instead?

Answer (score 8):

```
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments)
```

Works like this:

```
this.initialize(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], ...)
```

*Each item in arguments is passed as a parameter to `initialize()`*

Which is very different from just:

```
this.initialize(arguments)
```

*Pass `arguments` as the first and only parameter to `initialize()`*

In other words, if the function expects an array as the first parameter, use `this.initialize(arguments)`, otherwise use `.apply()`.